# How to use a third-party library within an angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I am trying to include a third party library within a library that I am developing.
To use this library in a normal angular application I need to do the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    GalleryModule.forRoot(), // <-- This is the library that I want to use
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But if I do it (GalleryModule.forRoot()) inside my module in the library it says that:

```
Error during template compile of 'BaseModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'GalleryModule' was called.
```

How can I include this library in my library?

**EDIT**

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 12.13.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 10.0.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
```

I am creating an angular library

```
ng new my-lib --create-application=false

cd my-lib
ng generate library my-lib
ng build
```

Then I installed the dependency:

```
npm install --save @ks89/angular-modal-gallery
npm install --save hammerjs mousetrap @angular/cdk
npm install --save-dev @types/mousetrap @types/hammerjs
```

Inside my library's package.json add the dependency to peerDependency:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.3",
    "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^7.2.5",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.5"
  }
```

Then add the dependency to the module inside the library:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GalleryModule } from '@ks89/angular-modal-gallery';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    GalleryModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class BaseModule { }
```

When I run:
ng build my-lib --prod

```
ERROR: projects/my-lib/node_modules/@ks89/angular-modal-gallery/lib/services/keyboard.service.d.ts:27:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ExtendedKeyboardEvent'.

27     add(onBind: (e: ExtendedKeyboardEvent, combo: string) => any): void;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/my-lib/node_modules/@ks89/angular-modal-gallery/lib/modal-gallery.module.d.ts:17:53 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

17     static forRoot(config?: KeyboardServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error during template compile of 'BaseModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'GalleryModule' was called.

An unhandled exception occurred: projects/my-lib/node_modules/@ks89/angular-modal-gallery/lib/services/keyboard.service.d.ts:27:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ExtendedKeyboardEvent'.

27     add(onBind: (e: ExtendedKeyboardEvent, combo: string) => any): void;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
projects/my-lib/node_modules/@ks89/angular-modal-gallery/lib/modal-gallery.module.d.ts:17:53 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

17     static forRoot(config?: KeyboardServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error during template compile of 'BaseModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'GalleryModule' was called.
```

Comment: I guess you'd share the code of `GalleryModule`.

Comment: GalleryModule is [https://github.com/Ks89/angular-modal-gallery](https://github.com/Ks89/angular-modal-gallery).
What I need is to use this module inside a component in my library

Comment: information in question is not adequate. post completely  Gallery version, angular version etc. Following is  official documentation example
https://github.com/Ks89/angular-modal-gallery/tree/master/examples/angular-cli/src

Comment: @MuniKumarGundu i updated my question, the problem is not using the gallery in an angular app, which works perfect. The problem is when using it within a library that I am building. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    GalleryModule,
  ]
})
export class BaseModule { }
```

Comment: Same error as above except `Error during template compile of 'BaseModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'GalleryModule' was called.`

Comment: Have you imported in your `tsconfig.json` the same types as listed here? https://github.com/Ks89/angular-modal-gallery/blob/master/projects/ks89/angular-modal-gallery/tsconfig.lib.json#L14